# GenyMotion is not Loading in my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-emulator, genymotion

I am getting problem on Launching the GenyMotion: 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Operating system.

I have Installed Virtual Box 4.3.18, then I have downloaded Genymoton and then I have downloaded Custom phone virtual device. At the time of launching the GenyMotion my system is getting complete hang. I am unable to move forward, I have no other option other then restarting.

I am using 64 bit Ubuntu machine. when I am trying to launch the virtual device directly from Virtual Box it loads fine. But, When I am trying to Launch from Eclipse, my machine getting hang.

Comment: how come you can start genymotion directly from "Virtual Box" main window? see: https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/support?chapter=virtual-machine-start-impossible#faq

Comment: Got the solution. It is the problem with my Video Driver. If you are using Nvidia Video card then need to follow this instruction: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia